# Missing reference while Converting VS2008 project to VS2010 project

Tags: visual-studio-2010

When i converted a VS2008 project to 2010 it shows an error message

> The type name 'IComponentConnector' could not be found in the namespace 'System.Windows.Markup'. This type has been forwarded to assembly 'System.Xaml, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089' Consider adding a reference to that assembly

and it was build when we add a reference `System.Xaml`. What would be the reason for need to add additional reference?

Answer (score 5):

In .Net 3.5/3,0, `IComponentConnector` (namespace `System.Windows.Markup`) was part of WindowsBase.dll and it was moved in System.Xaml in .net 4.0 onwards.

It seems you are upgrading your project framework 3.5 to 4.0

Answer (score 0):

The type was moved to the new assembly in .net 4?

You are changing you project to use .net 4 and it's telling you that you need this type from that assembly in .net 4.

if you target .net 3.5 you'll find you wont need to do this.

Answer (score 0):

As a thumb rule, always add the namespace that is documented. The document says to use the namespace System.Windows.Markup. It worked in VS2008 probably because System.Xaml was internally using the namespace System.Windows.Markup.